# How to move CCLayer in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

Can any one tell me how to move a CClayer. Like DoodleJump when object will move upward the background will also move upward.Plz Explain me with some sample code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move background in cocos 2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395959/how-to-move-background-in-cocos-2d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tutorial will teach you how to make a game very similar to doodle jump:
[Tutorial Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQfAj9pJuzw)

Hope it helps :)

P.S.
Check out this guys' channel he has the solution to your background problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use `CCFollow` actions.

Make your background sprite height some 1000 px.

```
[self runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:(u r hero) worldBoundary:CGRectMake(0,0,480,1050)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the tile maps code from the cocos2d sample code that is included with cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer to the question in the title is:

a CCLayer is a CCNode and can be moved by repositioning it:

```
myLayer.position = ccp(x,y);
```

Answer (score -1):

use ccaction like ccmoveby or ccmoveto , etc.,